# Is there a way to make directory listings open in new tabs?

Tags: html, directory

If I have a site that has a directory listing, such as [this one](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/), can I modify it to open in new tabs by default when someone clicks on a file or folder? Does this relate to the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that first you need to specify a header file in .htaccess:
`HeaderName header.html`
Then you need to place a "header.html" in the directory, and put this line in the file:
`<base target="_blank">`
Now every file in that directory will open in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Take this link for example. `<a href="/pub/OJI/" one-link-mark="yes">OJI/</a>`
Add attribute `target="_blank"`, and you'll get `<a href="/pub/OJI/" one-link-mark="yes" target="_blank">OJI/</a>`. Now, click the modified link will do.

Comment: Yes, I know of the target="_blank" attribute, but I don't think I can edit the raw directory listing links.

Comment: You can make a tampermonkey js, so that it'll automatically change the attributes of the links.